# How to Query what Salesforce SObjects a user has access to

Tags: soql, api, community, salesforce1-app, sosl

Please suggest How to Query what Salesforce SObjects a user has access to ?
Based on this i want to give access to user on particular apex tab menu .

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below could be used to iterate over all SObjects in your org and then check to see if they are accessible.

```
for (SObjectType so : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()) {
    DescribeSObjectResult describe = so.getDescribe();
    System.debug(describe.getName() + ' is ' + (describe.isQueryable() ? '' : ' not ') + 'accessible');
}
```

The above will print out something like:

> Account is accessible
>
> Contact is accessible
>
> Note is accessible
>
> Event is not accessible

See [DescribeSObjectResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) for other methods that are available

Comment: HiBarcotter,                                                                                                                  Thanks a lot ..Really Helpful Post ..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by access but you can use apex describe methods to find out if a user can see an object (isQueryable()), update an object (isUpdateable()) and delete and object (isDeleteable()).

```
SObjectType objectType = Foo__c.getSObjectType();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectResult = objectType.getDescribe();
System.debug('IS THIS OBJECT VISIBLE: ' + objectResult.isQueryable());
```